# In Symfony2 what is the best way to use a multi word name and get a good RESTful url

Tags: rest, symfony

I'm using the FOSRestBundle to build my symfony2 API.

I have entities called things like SupportRequestTemplate, which I would like to see in the API end point but when I create the Actions with names like

```
getSupportRequestTemplateAction(Request $request, $id) {}
```

FOSRest treats each camel case word as a new Resource name, so the url I get is

```
/api/supports/{id}/request/template.json
```

which looks pretty bad. Is there a way to get the end points to look like this instead.

```
/api/support-request-templates/{id}.json
```

Or will I just have to suck it up and go to all lower case for something like

```
/api/supportrequesttemplates/{id}.json
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use annotations to customise the url according to your needs.
For example `@Get`:

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;

/**
 * @Rest\Get("/api/support-request-templates/{id}.json")
 */
public function getSupportRequestTemplateAction($id, Request $request)
{
    ...
}
```

You can read more about these annotations in [manual definition of routes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/7-manual-route-definition.html).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, I had a couple of slight changes (removing some route info from the annotation that comes from .yml files) but otherwise it worked great.